# Trigger slideChange on response from server

Tags: json, amp-html

I've built an amp-carousel with a number of slides, each of which is relevant for a different time of day.

On pageload, I display an amp-list using some external JSON data. I would like to pass back in that JSON an indication of which slide should currently be displayed, and then call carousel.goToSlide to jump to that slide. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible as `carousel.goToSlide` only can be triggered by a user interaction. This could theoretically be supported by a `selected` attribute on a specific amp-carousel slide. You could file a feature request for this [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new).